# image.rows and image.cols are less than real image size (c++)

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am learning open cv, I wrote a code which is supposed to add salt and paper noise to the image(it turns some random pixel's value to 255), my image size is 256*256. The problem is I can't access to all pixels and the code just changes half of the image's pixels. For example, my image size as I said is  256*256 and when I change pixel value which is located in 256*256 it changes the center image's pixel.

```
inline cv::Mat salt(cv::Mat, int); //my function

int main()
{

     int present, imagepixel;
     cv::Mat image = cv::imread("sample.jpg");
     imagepixel = image.rows * image.cols;
     std::cout << "enter the value of salt and paper :";
     std::cin >> percent; 
     present = (present * imagepixel) / 100; //image pixel is number of image's pixels

     if (image.empty())
     {
          std::cout << "image is not valid" << std::endl;
     }

     image = salt(image, present);
     cv::imshow("salt&paper", image);
     cv::waitKey(0);
     return 0;
}

cv::Mat salt(cv::Mat image, int present)
{
     int row, col, j = 0;
     srand(time(NULL));
         
     for (int i = 0; i < present; i++)
     {
          row = rand() % image.rows;
          col = rand() % image.cols;
          image.at<unsigned char>(row, col) = 255;
     }
     return image;
}
```

1. Why does the image have more rows and columns than calculated with function like `image.rows` and `image.cols` (I give the value to image, in debugging mode and image, had value out of image.rows and image.cols range)?
2. Why is the output set to unsigned char? Why can't the value of pixels be an integer? (I supposed that inside `image.at<unsigned char>, <unsigned char>` is output kind `(int, char, float)`)
3. Why can't this code access all pixels? (screenshot has added look at the output)

[image: Description]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second argument of `imread` specifies how an image is read. Default value is `IMREAD_COLOR` what means that:

> In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels
>   stored in B G R order. ([from
>   reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56))

so your result *mat* has `256x256` resolution and each pixel is described by 3 values: to store *Blue*,*Green* and *Red* component of space color. These components are stored on `uchar` type (range is `[0,255)`).

2D images in OpenCV are stored row-by-row. The formula below can be used to calculate address of `M(row,col)` element:

```
addr(M[row,col]) = data + step1 * row + step2 * col
```

where `data` is first byte of array where the data of image is stored. Your *mat* has 3 channels and image's width is `256`, so `step1` equals to `256 * 3` (it is number of columns in row multiplied by number of channels per pixel) and `step2` is `3`.

Now, let's open source code of `at` member function:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
_Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1) {
    return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * i0))[i1];
}
// i0 means row, i1 means col
```

in your code you specify `_Tp` as `uchar`. Now just rules of pointer arithmetic work which cause you can access only *1/3* of input image. For example when you call `<uchar>(0,1)` you are accessing *Green* component of `(0,0)` pixel.

To resolve your issue you have to pass `Vec3b` in template argument list:

```
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(row, col) = cv::Vec3b(255,255,255);
```

(each component of Vec3b has `uchar` type).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. my image is black and white. cant it be a reason for being one channel image?

Comment: If your input image is JPG with grayscale, when `imread` with `IMREAD_COLOR` output image will have 3 channels and all channels have the same value. You could call `imread` with `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` and then access mat's elements by `at<uchar>` - your output mat will have one channel, it should work.

Comment: and whats default for imread? (imread without _grayscare or _color)